# Must the the adverb "though" always convey a sense of contrast?

Tags: adverbs, spoken-english

I know "though" can be used as an adverb in a sentence, especially in spoken English. I was taught to use "though" when the context includes some sort of contrast or conflicting ideas.

However, I hear the native use the adverb in the sentences which barely carries with it any sort of conflict. For instance,

> I got a date tomorrow though.

Is there any latent or hidden conflicting idea that I'm failing to get?

Is it a self-depreciating statement? That's the only contrast I can think of.

Comment: I've got a date tomorrow, though. The **though** contrasts with something said before that. Self-deprecating, no. I got a date means you were able to get it. It is not referring to something actually in your sentence, but to something else said by someone else or even you.

Comment: Where in the world (literally) are these native speakers you're hearing?  Who say "I got a date tomorrow though" out of the blue, with no context to explain the contradictory or conflicting situation that **though** needs?

Comment: @Tromano In the us.

Comment: Are you sure they're saying **though** and not **yo**?

Comment: Yes almost sure, because I think I can destinguish the tho sounds from yo.

Comment: Just in case -- **yo** is a discourse marker in AAVE (and is also used by non-blacks emulating that speech).

Comment: Context: It was a long discussion and he said he's goining to do something in the next week. And suddenly the though sentence comes ( I will add this to the question) Sorry.

Comment: Well, then the conflict was possibly divulged at some point during the long conversation, and there is always the possibility that it was something he had in mind but had not voiced, or thought he had told you about earlier.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Context matters here.

> Janet, let's go to the party tomorrow.
>
> -- I've got a date tomorrow, though.
>
> Oh, OK then. I'll find someone else to go with.

The *though* here contrasts with the first speaker's assertion that they will be going to the party. You're missing context in your question that would likely help provide an answer.

Comment: Thanks for the answer and I am sorry that I didn't mention the context. I will edit the question. However, I put it in comment above.